# sailsjs - what's the best way to track rooms at app level

Tags: websocket, sails.js

[sails.sockets.rooms()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/sails-sockets-rooms) and [sails.sockets.socketRooms()](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/sails-sockets/sails-sockets-socket-rooms) are both deprecated

In the doc:

> This method is deprecated. Please keep track of your rooms in app-level code.

I am new to SailsJS.

**Question 1**: How could I get started with that? Where should I declare my room array or hash?

**Question 2**: How do I get the list of the clients connected?

Answer (score 5):

Here the way I did it. Hope this helps a little, although I am not confident it's perfect, BUT it worked for me. Feel free to suggest corrections, enhancements.

I declared a `sails.rooms = {};` in the controller (**Question 1**) where I needed it most. (You can name it whatever you want.)

`sails.` gives it access across the application.

#### In the controller

```
  /**
   * Socket connection
   */
  connect: function(req, res) {
     // Check if it's socket connection
     if (!req.isSocket) { return res.badRequest(); } 

     // label the room to ROOM_NAME
     sails.sockets.join(req, ROOM_NAME);

     /**
      * Manage my `sails.rooms` HERE
      * e.g. 
      */
      if (!sails.rooms[ROOM_NAME]) {
        sails.rooms[ROOM_NAME] = {};
      }
      sails.rooms[ROOM_NAME][req.socket.id] = HUMAN_FRIENDLY_LABEL;
  }
```

I end up with a JSON that looks like this:

```
{
   { "room1" : 
     {
       "ksadj1234clkjnelckjna" : "john",
       "eroiucnw934cneo3vra09" : "marie"
     }
   },
   { "room2" : 
     {
       "kslaksdjfnasjdkfa9jna" : "antoine",
       "qweuiqcnw934cne3vra09" : "michelle"
    }
   }
}
```

#### In `config/sockets.js`, I manage disconnections

```
  afterDisconnect: function(session, socket, cb) {
    console.log(socket.id + " disconnected");
    /**
     * Manage sails.rooms HERE
     * e.g.
     */
    for (r in sails.rooms) {
      delete sails.rooms[r][socket.id];
      //
      // YOUR CODE
      //
    }

    return cb();
  },
```

> **NOTE**: that you can list the WebSockets in a certain room using `sails.io.sockets.in(ROOM_NAME)`. This should also help to purge the `sails.rooms` from disconnected sockets.